# Ошибка в тернарном операторе

Tags: php

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. На моем хостинге вот такая запись успешно работает:

```
$height = $height ?: $width;
```

Однако на другом хостинге он выбрасывает:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in ...

Почему так? Настройка php.ini или версия самого PHP?

Comment: А зачем нужно такое издевательство над тернарным оператором? Вставьте туда какое-нибудь значение ($height тот же)

Comment: На «другом» хостинге явно другая версия php. ?: стало доступным лишь с PHP 5.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Начиная с версии PHP 5.3** также стало возможным не писать среднюю часть тернарного оператора. Выражение expr1 ?: expr3 возвращает expr1
>   если expr1 имеет значение TRUE, и expr3 в другом случае.

http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Хм, а что, `expr1 || expr3` в пыхе нельзя делать?

Answer (score 1):

Эта фича, сокращённый тернарный оператор, появилась начиная с PHP 5.3.
Так что на другом хостинге у вас просто более старый PHP.

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the
>   conditional operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1
>   evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.

Подробнее:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0):

Версия PHP. Опускать второй операнд возможно с версии 5.3.

Цитата с офф. сайта:

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.

Т.е. ваше выражение эквивалентно `$height = $height ? $height : $width;`

Советую так код и писать, если есть вероятность, что скрипт будет запущен на сервере с более старой версией PHP.